# Construction of a strictly increasing continuous function.

Tags: continuity, fixed-point-theorems, monotone-functions

I'm studying Vittorino Pata's article and I have a doubt about the possibility of constructing a **strictly increasing continuous function**
$\mu$
such that
$$\mu(0)=0$$
and $$\mu(r) \leq 1- \frac{\rho(r)}{r}, \forall r \in [0,1],$$
where 
$$\rho: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow [0, \infty)$$ is a continuous increasing function satisfying $$\rho(r)<r, \  \textrm{if} \ \ r>0.$$
(the kind of functions that we have on Boyd-Wong type results).

Thanks a lot for any help.

Best,

Cleto

Comment: @MichaelBurr TThe condition is just $\mu(r)\le 1-\rho(r)/r$ for $r\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks, you're right.  I didn't read carefully enough to see the domain of $r$ was compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the structure of $1-\rho(r)/r$ is irrelevant:

> > If $\psi:(0,1]\to(0,1]$ is continuous there exists a strictly increasing continuous $\mu:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with  $\mu(0)=0$ and $\mu\le\psi$.

Proof: Let $$\mu(r)=r\min_{r\le s\le 1}\psi(s).$$

Comment: Is $t$ supposed to be $r$ in the minimum?

Comment: @JoelPereira  Eewps. Thanks...